# How to access QFieldCloud Projects functionality in QField App?

Tags: qgis, qfield

I checked my QField App and the **QFieldCloud Projects** functionality is already enabled (See photo attached). However, whenever I try to access or use it, it looks for username/password credentials.

I already pre-registered from the https://qfield.cloud/ website, but I haven't received yet any confirmation email or the needed credentials to use or test this function in QField App. I also checked my colleagues' QField App and their QFieldCloud Projects function is still greyed out, so I am thinking that mine was already activated since I pre-registered earlier than them.

Is there a way I can use or test QFieldCloud capability or get the needed credentials for it to work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the current beta version of the app (QField 2.0.2) while your colleagues use the productive release 1.9.6. In the beta version (next to all the other new features) the cloud functionalities are enabled for all the QFieldCloud testers. Keep up. QFieldCloud testers are currently being added on a regular basis. You will receive an activation email when this is the case. And QFieldCloud will go public soon anyway. All needed information will be provided then as well.